# Changing Text Content Externally VIA OSC

Tags: text-object

I am new to Blender and am using AddOSC to manipulate Blender objects "on the fly". I would like to be able to change *text content* using Open Sound Control. However, as far as can make out text objects do not have text content available as a readily accessible property. (I have been using Blenders' excellent ' code reveal' facility which is activated when hovering over fields to get the necessary assignment addresses for OSC). I find this lack of a simple content property box surprising as in most other programs text content is an assignable text property usually available within a properties panel.

The only solution I have found that sort of works is by making the text object editable via a script and then changing text content that way but this method lacks responsiveness and flexibility and works against the OSC approach.

It seems odd that Blender has such a wealth of capability in the visual presentation of text but that the control of content seems less important - or maybe Im missing something? I would be grateful for any suggestions as to a way forward.

Thx in advance.